# I want to know the average value based on row and column value

Tags: python

dataframe:

| id | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3.5 | 4.5 | 3 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 4.5 | 2 | 5 |
| 2 | 4 | 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 | 3.5 |
| 3 | 2 | 1.5 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | 0 | 2 |

waht i want:

| id | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2.25 | 3.25 | 3.5 |
| 2 | 4.25 | 2.5 | 3 |
| 3 | 2.67 | 1.25 | 2.5 |

I want to know the average based on the id and each category.

Comment: what did you try? show your code and what went wrong.

Comment: Refer this, https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html#pandas-core-groupby-groupby-mean

Comment: so sorry, i am poor on python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY:

```
mean = df.groupby('id', as_index=False).mean()
```

Comment: hi, it  works now, but, but if i want remove the one of id, like this, id_4 = training[(training.userId == 4)]，training = training[(training.userId != 4)], it said that there is no name for userId